# How to plugin function code move to theme function.php ? I've tried below code but not working

Tags: plugin-development, functions

```
add_filter('get_public_descriptions', 'theme_get_public_descriptions_filter');

 function theme_get_public_descriptions_filter ($context, $rule_uids)
    {
        $descriptions = array();

        $rule_uids = (array) $rule_uids;

        // Check if at least one rule uid is set
        if (!empty($rule_uids) && is_array($rule_uids)) {

            // Get rules by uids
            $rules = RP_WCDPD_Rules::get($context, array('uids' => $rule_uids), true);

            // Iterate over applicable rules and append their public descriptions
            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                if (isset($rule['public_note']) && !RightPress_Helper::is_empty($rule['public_note'])) {

                    $descriptions [$rule['uid']]= $rule['public_note'];
                }
            }
        }

        return !empty($descriptions) ? $descriptions : null;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: plugin function move to theme function.php file .

Comment: For? Maybe there's an easy filter which can do what you are trying to do, it'd be better if you can expand your question and mention what you want to do and what all you tried already.

Comment: i need to contact form plugin function code overwrite  to theme function.php file.any feature plugin update not affect to the my custom code

Comment: so what all you tried and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: i'll tried more code but not coming result ? please tel exact demo reference code post here.very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that the file should be named `functions.php`, not `function.php` as you have consistently called it.

See [Functions File Explained](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) on the Codex.